# Mailchimp - Embedded form for email subscribe form

Tags: javascript, forms, email, backend, mailchimp

this is not specifically a coding question but still related to web development.

I'm using Mailchimp embedded form to create an email subscription for users and I have a few questions.

1. I used the embedded form for my site and when the user is putting in their email then click subscribe, it will take them to another window which is a mailchimp form but instead of that. Is there anyway I can have the email go directly to mailchimp and just have a thank message on the form without sending the user to the external mailchimp link?
2. I created a checkbox for the privacy agreement from mailchimp form. Is there anyway to make that checkbox a requirement? I didn't see mailchimp build form have any option for that.

Thank you. Any help is appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--add below near the top of form-->
<div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates 
required</div>
<!--start out like below-->
<label for="mce-FNAME">First Name</label>
<!--can do it how it is below-->
<label for="mce-FNAME">First Name<span class="asterisk">*</span>
</label>
<!--so you add the below-->
<span class="asterisk">*</span>
```